# Completion Handler in API never runs

Tags: arrays, swift, api

I have an APICall as below

```
static func getLinkToken() {
        // Prepare URL
        let url = URL(string: "https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/token/create")
        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
        // Prepare URL Request Object
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
  
        let prePostString : [String : Any] = [
            "client_id" : clientID,
            "secret" : secret,
            "user" : ["client_user_id": uniqueID],
            "client_name": "Plaid App",
            "products": ["transactions"],
            "country_codes": ["US"],
            "language": "en",
            "account_filters": [
                 "depository": [
                     "account_subtypes": ["checking"]
                 ]
             ]
        ]

        let postString = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: prePostString)
        
        
        // Set HTTP Request Body
        request.httpBody = postString;
        
        
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
        // Perform HTTP Request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                
                // Check for Error
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error took place \(error)")
                    return
                }
         
            do {
                //Parse response into a dict
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
                
                //Add link token to user class
                User.linkToken = (parsedData["link_token"] as! String)
                
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
              }
            
                // Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
                    
                   
                    
                }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
```

For some reason this code never works if I call it unless it is in `@main.init`.
It appears that when I call the function in any class/method other than the initializer for main, the completion handler never runs. An example of how I call it is shown below.

```
class Practice {

     func getAPI() {

         getLinkToken()

    }

}
```

TLDR; completion handler in API call never runs.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it doesn’t run? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: Yes - I have placed a print statement inside the completion handler and when I run the method from the main - init, the method prints, and I get the data I need to run the rest of my program. I placed a breakpoint at several points throughout my code at every line but it won't run.

Comment: It works for me:    Response data string:
 {
  "display_message": null,
  "documentation_url": "https://plaid.com/docs/?ref=error#invalid-request-errors",
  "error_code": "INVALID_BODY",
  "error_message": "body could not be parsed as JSON",
  "error_type": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "request_id": "rdXvTWrgOTWZsVM",
  "suggested_action": null
}

Comment: That is actually quite annoying - where are you running it from? Could I see how you call it?

Comment: If you call static method it should be ClassName.getLinkToken()

Comment: Yeah that's what I have - I mistyped